# Fetch Windows system temperature with Java

Tags: java, windows-7, jna, temperature

I wrote a small hack that uses Java JNA and TCP sockets to transmit battery information from a Windows 7 system to other systems on my network, and I'd now like to add thermal monitoring functionality to it. Is it possible to monitor system thermal statistics from JNA?

Edit: Forgot to mention that I need a "pure Java" solution (but JNA and friends are permitted); I'm in a horrible environment that ensures I can't run applications that aren't digitally signed, I don't have access to the digital signature list, and I can't disable the digital signature lockdowns.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117043/what-is-the-best-way-for-a-java-program-to-monitor-system-health

Comment: This question has far narrower scope, and much tighter restrictions;  for instance, I don't have the option to use SNMP.  I need a "pure Java" solution for the reasons that I've mentioned in a comment to the answer @Snicolas submitted.

Answer (score 3):

Most stuff I've read shows that manufacturers use WMI to expose this information. To allow your Java program to access WMA, check out this thread: [Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java)

Comment: That might, under other circumstances, work. On this circumsized system, it seems I don't have the necessary WMI providers for thermal sensing.  That's a good solution for other things, though, and I'm going to persue it.

Answer (score 0):

If you could find a command line utility that works on windows to get sys temp you could call it from a processbuilder in Java.

Stephane

Comment: One of the things that disqualifies this is that I need a "pure Java" solution; I'm in a horrible environment that ensures I can't run applications that aren't digitally signed, I don't have access to the digital signature list, and I can't fix it.  Sorry.

Comment: So if you don t have wmi and must found java solution, you can t.